# How do I obtain meta data from GCP bucket objects like author, latest version, Gsuite URI, etc?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am using the java GCP SDK and want to save some information about an object to a postgreSQL table right after creating it. I have found methods using the Blob type and various getter methods for that type but there are more that I need such as URI, author, last updated, latest author, and many more. Is there somewhere I can see a list of all available methods to get this type of data?

I have tried getting the URI by a few different methods and have ended up using the method below

```
String gUri = blob.getSelfLink();
System.out.println("Gsuite URI: "+URI.create(gUri));
```

This method returns a regular URL not a URI and then furthermore I would have to parse it and add a few thigs. Is there a way to get the URI directly from google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Java class [Blob](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage/2.16.0/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html) we seem to find that it extends [BlobInfo](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage/2.16.0/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.html) which contains a lot of properties including:

- `getOwner()` - The owner of the blob.
- `getSelfLink()` - The URL of the blob.
- `getUpdateTimeOffsetDateTime()` - The last update time.
- `getGeneration()` - The current generation (version) of the blob.

As for the identity of a Blob ... it should be composed of two parts ... the bucket name as returned by `getBucket()` and the blob name as returned by `getName()`.

Comment: this seems to work well, if there are subfolders will I have to know that sub folder or how does that work? I understand I can do something like below
```
System.out.println("gs://"+<bucket_name>+"/"+<file_path_inside_bucket>);
```
but what if there is a sub folder in between the bucket and object is there a way to account for that?

Comment: To me, folders are an "illusion" in GCS (Google Cloud Storage) ... see:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

What this means is that there are ONLY files (blobs) and those files are named and in the name the "/" character is literally part of the name of the file.  Logically, an application can "treat" the "/" as a delimiter ... so if I have files "f/x.txt" and "f/y.txt" we can logically say that "x.txt" and "y.txt" and in a folder called "f" but from a GCS perspective we ONLY have files called "f/x.txt" and "f/y.txt".